# Is Firebase's free service less fast than the paid service?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

***Flutter Dart Firbase Firstore***

well , all I know is that the difference is in the storage space in all  Firebase's services

**But my question is, is there also a difference in the speed of performance and data processing from within the application?**

Because I recently noticed that if an operation was performed on 50 documents, for example, whether it was a process of deletion, import or modification. There is an inappropriate result of serving a giant like `Firebase`

Well let's say I deleted 50 documents from within the app and then I wanted to do another operation right after that. There is a delay in response estimated at 3 minutes.. I tested this thing several times and from real devices and with professionally programmed codes..

I am preparing for a big project and I want an answer to this question in order to decide if I should subscribe to them or look for another server with a faster speed

Is the nature of Firebase's service so bad for official applications, or are these limited policies?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("example").doc().get().//any proces()  with large docs
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Is there also a difference in the speed of performance and data processing from within the application?

No, there is not.  The payment tier doesn't in any way gate the performance of the underlying cloud resources.  The payment tier just places limits on now much can be used.

A full explanation of the differences between the payment tiers can be seen in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

If you have questions about pricing, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for answer Doug , but i didn't ask about pricing because i already know their  pricing policies

Comment: I know, but *if you do*, you know where best to go.

Comment: As Doug said: all projects run on the same infrastructure, regardless of the plan they're on.